# How to add the elements into the Map where key is String and Value is List[String] in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have [a text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H98Hb.png) which contains information about the sender and messages. The format is sender, messages.

I've loaded the file into a RDD and split them by "," and created a key value pair, where key is sender and value is messages `RDD[(String,String)]`.

Then, I did a `groupByKey()` to group the messages based on sender and I got a `RDD[(String,Iterable[String])]`.

```
Array[(String, Iterable[String])] = Array((Key,CompactBuffer(value1,value2,value3,....))
```

Now, I want to iterate the value part, and stores the values one by one to the List, so I've created a empty Map where key is String and value is `List[String]`

First I should check whether the Map is empty, if it is empty then I should add the first value to the List which is present inside the Map.

The below is whatever I've tried but I could not do it, when I've checked the Map it's shows None.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
object Demo{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My App")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  val inputFile = "D:\\MyData.txt"
  val data = sc.textFile(inputFile)
  val data2 = data.map(line => {val arr = line.split(","); 
   (arr(0),arr(1))})
  val grpData = data2.groupByKey()
  val myMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String,List[String]]
  for(value <- grpData.values){
    val list = ListBuffer[String]()
    if(myMap.isEmpty){
      list += value
      myMap.put("G1", list.toList)
    }
  }
}
```

In the for loop, I gave grpData.values because I need only the value part. I don't want the keys whatever I have in my file as a sender. I Just used them to group the messages based on the sender, but in the Map[String,List[String]] my key should be Group1, Group2 and so on. The value is messages whatever I will get one by one from the CompactBuffer.

First, I should check whether the Map is empty, If it is empty I should add the first message to the List which is present inside the Map. Key should be "Group1" and value should be the message that should be stored in List[String].

For the second Iteration, Map will not be empty then the condition will go to the else part, In the else part I should use lavenshtein distance algorithm to compare the messages. Here first message was already added to the List, now I should get the first message from Map and compare it with second message using lavenshtein distance algorithm with threshold of 70%. If the 2 messages meets the threshold then I should add the second message to the List, If not I should add second message to the separate list and keep the key name as "G2" and so on.

Comment: Can you add like a sample input with the expected output so we can understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sure, I will do that.

Comment: Explaining imperatively is not enough. You are assuming that the steps you take are correct or the most ideal. Show us sample inputs and expected results.

Comment: No, I've just explained my requirement, I've never assumed that I'm correct. I've added my sample input please check. I do not have any output sample, I've explained that I should find the similar messages using lavenshtein distance algorithm and store them in a List. Thanks

Comment: Dont explain the steps to take. Come up with a trivial input and an expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I'm a new user and I will do that it future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregateByKey` to get a combined list of strings for each key:

```
val data = sc.textFile(inputFile)
val data2 = data.map(line => {val arr = line.split(","); (arr(0),arr(1))})
val result = data2.aggregateByKey(List[String]())(_ :+ _, _ ++ _)

// or to prepend rather than append,
// val result = data2.aggregateByKey(List[String]())((x, y) => y :: x, _ ++ _)
```

If you want the result as a `Map`, you can do

```
val resultMap = result.toMap
```

Comment: Thank you so much, actually my requirement is little different that's was the reason I've used Map[String, List[String]]. I will edit my question and explain briefly, please check and help me.

Comment: Anyhow appending to a list with `:+` should not be advised due to it's linear time complexity.

Comment: @yangzai do you have any better suggestions?

Comment: Prepend the element in the list o(1) operation

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are trying to cluster base off some distance function, in which this might be what you are looking for:

```scala
def isWithinThreshold(s1: String, s2: String): Boolean = ???

//2 sets are grouped when there exist elements in a both sets that are closed to each other
def combine(acc: Vector[Vector[String]], s: Vector[String]) = {
  val (near, far) = acc.partition(_.exists(str => s.exists(isWithinThreshold(str, _))))

  near.fold(s)(_ ++ _) +: far
}

val preClusteringGroups = grpData.values.map(_.toVector) //this is already pre-grouped with with the key from data2 (`arr(0)`)
val res = preClusteringGroups.aggregate(Vector.empty[Vector[String]])(combine, { case (v1, v2) =>
  (v1 ++ v2).foldLeft(Vector.empty[Vector[String]])(combine)
}).zipWithIndex.map { case (v, i) => s"G$i" -> v }.toMap //.mapValues(_.toList) if you actually need a list
```

`preClusteringGroups` is based of `grpData` which is already pre-grouped by the orginal key and might not fulfill your distance requirements. If that' the case redefine `preClusteringGroups` with:

```scala
val preClusteringGroups = data2.values.map(Vector(_))
```